# Keras trained mode always predicts 0

Tags: keras, classification

I'm trying to build a model to predict wether a picture has text in it using keras with Tensorflow backend.

This is my Model:

```python
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(image_size, image_size, 3))) # 32?
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) # 0.5?

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3))) # again, 32?
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) # again, 0.5?

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3))) # again, 64?
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) # again, 0.5?

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(96))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1)) # binary
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I've tried image sizes 128, 256, 384.
I train it with 9000 images, 4500 of cat 1 and 4500 of cat 2.
the training accuracy goes as high as 0.90.
but when I load the model and use it to predict the category of images of the two categories that I haven't trained it with, it always gives the score 0.

Any ideas why this is happenning?

p.s. cat 1 is images with text and cat 2 is images without text.

also this is my code for testing the model:

```python
model = load_model(model_path)

test_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
test_generator = test_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    test_data_dir,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=False)

prediction = model.predict_generator(
    test_generator,
    use_multiprocessing=True,
    verbose=1)  # verbose=1 makes it show a progress bar.

dst = []
for pred in prediction:
    if int(round(pred)) == 0:
        dst += [0]
    else:
        dst += [1]
```

dst is all 0's.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was that I used keras' generators to feed the images I was testing and used shutil to iterate over them. So I'd get the predictions and iterate over them and the files in the directory using two different things and the order of them wasn't the same. shutil would list them in some random order whereas the generator would list them in ascending order by name. so I wasn't putting a label on the file it was generated for.